# Why and when we can omit std keyword in C++?

Tags: c++, stl, c++14, argument-dependent-lookup

Both this code:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> v;

  std::exchange(v, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5});

  copy(cbegin(v), cend(v) - 1, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
  std::cout << *rbegin(v) << "\n\n";

  return 0;
}
```

and this code:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> v;

  std::exchange(v, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5});

  std::copy(std::cbegin(v), std::cend(v) - 1, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
  std::cout << *std::rbegin(v) << "\n\n";

  return 0;
}
```

can be compiled (in C++14 and C++17) successfully and do the same job. But I wonder why I can omit `std::` as well as in what circumstance?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl

Comment: The symbol `std` is not a keyword, it's a normal `namespace` identifier defined in standard C++ headers (with e.g. `namespace std { ... }`).

Comment: @tadman As you can see my code did not have that expression, but it just work. You may try with your compiler.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude okay that's my mistake.

Comment: Whereas `std::vector` is in namespace `std`, it is not necessary the case for `std::vector::const_iterator` (which might even be `const int*`).